# Composer hangs at FOS user-bundle on production server

Tags: symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle

I've been trying to deploy my Symfony app via capifony and composer hangs at the same point every time on my production server. Locally I have no problems when running `composer update`.

I run `cap deploy` and...

```
[snip]...
  * Loading from cache
  * Extracting archive
  * - Updating friendsofsymfony/user-bundle dev-master (d5b28c3 => e39b040)
  * Checking out e39b040e272c72f0a090c67d802e1d3b2d0b0313
--> Updating parameters
    Pulling in changes:
  e39b040 - Christophe Coevoet: Mark legacy tests as legacy
  ...
  [snipped for length]
  ...
  da8100c - Daniel Ancuta: Pass missing parameter to "trans" function.
[hangs from here]
```

I've tried locking various bundles to different versions and I still encounter the same problem.

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.33",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.0-alpha3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.0.1",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "dev-master",
    "eko/feedbundle": "1.2.6",
    "jms/payment-paypal-bundle": "*",
    "jms/payment-core-bundle": "dev-master",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "paypal/merchant-sdk-php":"v3.8.107",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "v0.8",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "v0.8",
    "orderly/paypal-ipn-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "0.1.*",
    "amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php": "1.6.2",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "dev-master",
    "azine/email-bundle": "1.0.3",
    "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Checked if you respect the GitHub API limit?

Comment: @PiWi Thanks. On bitbucket I don't see that I've hit any limits, and it doesn't seem likely to me. Is there a special way to check?

Comment: Try commenting out one by one the items after "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle"

Comment: Most composer packages are hosted on GitHub. Probably you did hit the API limit of GitHub. You can confirm this by running composer install on your production server manually. You can prevent this by adding a GitHub token to your composer. More info about this at the composer website: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens

Comment: @PiWi I found the solution. All I had to do was hit Enter to continue the deployment! Very silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling, I found this:

https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/549

Apparently sometimes you have to hit ENTER during the deployment process. I just waited and would give up hitting CTRL+C. I ended up needing to hit enter several times for it to finish. This hasn't happened in the 2 years I've been deploying like this.